# Not able to run protractor test with phantomjs

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

I am using protractor to test Angular code. The test is running fine when i am running it via chrome driver that comes by default with webdriver-manager. Now I want to run same test with phantomjs (headless browser) as i need to run this test via server. But while running test via phantomjs I am getting error:

> Failed: Angular could not be found on the page URL : retries looking for angular exceeded

Conf file is:

```
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['demo-test.js'],
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'phantomjs',
  version: '',
  platform: 'ANY'
};
```

demo-test.js file looks like:

```
// demo-test.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000000;

beforeEach(function() {
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
});
it('should have a title', function() {
  browser.get('URL');

  expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Title');

});
```

Please help me out. I have installed protractor by using instructions from official [site](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial) and installed phantomjs via

`sudo apt-get install phantomjs`

Comment: I would not recommend phantomJS with protractor. Instead try using XVFB with chrome on your server to run the browser with a virtual display.

Comment: Hey @martin770 thanks for your suggestion, can you provide any link of document where i can find how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You increasing wrong timeout:

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000000;
```

This timeout is for jasmine test not to run for too long. If you want to wait for page load and angular on the page longer - add this to protractor config file:

```
getPageTimeout: timeout_in_millis  //default 10 sec
allScriptsTimeout: timeout_in_millis  //default 11 sec
```

More about timeouts here - http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

Also check that you point to correct root element:

```
  // CSS Selector for the element housing the angular app - this defaults to
  // body, but is necessary if ng-app is on a descendant of <body>.
  rootElement: 'body',
```

I would not recomend runnning protractor tests on phantomJS, it works really differently from real browsers, and sometimes you might skip real bugs, or find something specific to phantomJS.

Comment: Use chrome, or firefox if most of your users on it.